# SMS Journey Builder Salesforce Contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect

I have created a journey which is pulling data from salesforce and sending email to the salesforce contact.

But SMS is not working I have created Interaction outbound message Template.

I have added SMS interaction in the journey but I am not receiving any SMS but I am receiving email.

Can you please help ?

Did I miss any setting for SMS.

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any errors? Can you share the logs?

Answer (score 2):

There is configuration option in the SEND SMS > SUBSCRIBER OPT-IN METHOD > **Choose Subscribe all contacts to a keyword** which will add all the new contacts emails to the journey and will automatically get added to the **ALL CONTACTS in Mobile Connect**.

If we don't choose this option the Contacts with Mobile Numbers will enter the journey never get sent unless the Mobile number already exists in the ALL CONTACTS or imported of all contacts done by file import.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the mobile phone field of the Data Extension where you have contact data in the contact configuration's section that you can find into the contact builder.

In this way your journey will send the SMS using values of this field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! do you have any guild or example.I am pulling these contact from salesforce.

Comment: Sorry @Praneet i don't have any guide, anyway i show you where you can find documentation (https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/contacts_configuration/). For example i imported a Data Extension where i have Mobile field with Phone Number as data type; then i added this field in channel address order for SMS into Contact Configuration. In this way the journey will use the value of Mobile field in order to send SMS to th customers.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where SFMC have got with this, but I heard there's an imminent update to the Send SMS Activity coming that creates a MobileConnect contact for you if the contact does not already exist in MobileConnect. Current functionality doesn't do this and the SMS Send will fail within Journey Builder if the contact is not already in MobileConnect. You've typically had to create an Automation to run periodically to import your contacts into MobileConnect to make Journey Builder SMSs to work. Not at all ideal, but that's been the case until now.

Comment: @Macca, do you know if this is still the case or have recent JB updates resolved this limitation?

Comment: @AnonWonderer , Yes this issue is partially resolved by SFMC in the August 2017 release.  http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/august_2017_release/mobile_studio/#sms  This will allow you to subscribe contacts’ phone numbers in real-time to a keyword of your choice as they hit the activity.  As far as I have tested this is working for automation audience, email audience. It is not working with the Salesforce data as audience